# Get the color from the night folder on Android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have two folders

values-night -> colors.xml

```
<color name="iconColor">#ffffff</color>
```

values -> colors.xml

```
<color name="iconColor">#000000</color>
```

When I want to read 'iconColor'

Normally with code

```
ContextCompat.getColor(this,R.color.iconColor)
```

If night mode is enabled, it reads from the values-night folder

If night mode is not enabled, it reads from the values folder

**Now I want to read the `values-night` folder under any circumstances**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dedicated color for "night" mode, use that in the `-night` folder, and then reference it directly as necessary:

`values/colors.xml`:

```
<color name="iconColor">#000000</color>
<color name="nightModeColor">#FFFFFF</color>
```

`values-night/colors.xml`

```
<color name="iconColor">@color/nightModeColor</color>
```

Then, in code, to use "night mode color" under "any circumstance":

```
ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.nightModeColor)
```

Hope that helps!